# Found a cut hose

Tags: coolant, cooling-system

My 1992 Lexus ES300 has been leaking fluids really bad lately, which it never did. I believed some foul play was involved due to certain individual whom I live with. Anyhow yesterday I was just looking to find why is there so much fluids discharging from the front portion of the engine.

I found a hose coming out of the box shaped cover where the throttle cable goes to. The hose is cut in a diagonal manner and fluids were dripping from it. How can I find out where it goes.

I also went under to find 2 more hose clamps to be in the wrong place, meaning at the edge so they would fail soon. Those 2 hoses are at the bottom of the radiator but I don't see any other cut hoses or a missing place.

Symptoms of the poor performance, stalls at idle and sluggish to take off. Also the fan is overworking at high always. Help me fix this issue please.

Comment: Can you describe the fluid coming from the cut hose by the throttle? Also if you could add pictures, I think they would help.

Comment: Most likely the coolant hose to the idle air control valve. Check the coolant, if it low it is best not to run the engine due to possible overheating.

Comment: 1)  1992 vehicle?  Hoses get old, and crack.  Normal life for a hose is up to 10 years, not 25 years.  When they crack it certainly can look just like a knife cut.  2) Not sure what hose you are talking about.  Perhaps you know somebody that has a smart phone or digital camera?   A picture tells us a whole lot about what is going on.

Comment: Cutting a hose seems like a petty way to sabotage a car - hoses are some of the cheapest and easiest parts to replace.  If they really wanted to do damage, surely they could be more creative.